# Stale element error when scrolling down a dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to scroll down a dropdown to get to the hidden option with this code, but it's not scrolling down and getting stale element error in console.

```java
List<WebElement> getLevelsList = webDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@role='option'][1]"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", getLevelsList.get(5));
```

Comment: Please provide more detail like URL, HTML or any other info about the issue.

Comment: stale element means that between the time you get the webelement array "getLevelsList" and the time you perform the .get(5) (or the javascript scroll method) on it, the DOM has updated so that the element reference is stale.  (get it again... or get only what you need... the single element and use a webdriverwait and/or sleep.  If you don't want to use a sleep, you can functionize the call and re-call when/if stale element is caught.

Comment: When you proceed manualy, if you need to click that dropdown to be able to scroll down, webdriver will need that click as well.